# A question about a sum of squares of uniform random variables

Tags: self-study, uniform-distribution

For independent and identical $V_1,V_2\in U(-1,1)$, what is the probability that $V_1^2+V_2^2<1$?

I tried but can't get an answer, the answer is $\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Are the $V_1$ and $V_2$ independent? What have you tried?

Comment: @mpiktas yes! they are independent, actually I can't find Idea.

Comment: HINT: Your condition gives a circle, the pythagorean theorem.

Comment: I suggest that you draw the curve $V_1^2+V_2^2=1$ and the curve $|V_1|+|V_2|=1$ ;-)

Comment: Draw a picture, and show all your calculations.

Comment: I did (area of radius 1)/(area of radius 2)

Comment: @TommyL, Surely you meant curve $\max\{|V_1|,|V_2|\}=1$?

Comment: @mpiktas Oh, yes, of course! It should be $\max(|V_1|,|V_2|)=1$ for the second curve!

Comment: This is trivial - draw a picture, write down the answer.

Comment: @Glen_b yes but I get 1/4

Comment: $$\iint_{x^2+y^2 \leq 1} \frac 14\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy = \int_{r=0}^1\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \frac 14 r\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm dr$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: ohhh @DilipSarwate :) Yes! its me confused! and thank you so much I realize I missed $\theta$

Answer (score 1):

Just draw a graph of it; replace V1 and V2 with x and y respectively. You should have a circle with side length 2 centred about the origin. Then draw a graph of x^2 + y^2 = 1, which is a unit circle centred about the origin. The answer would be the area of that circle divided by the area of the square.

Comment: That does not seem to make sense to me. How do you draw a circle of side 2? Do you mean a square?